# __block on Windows in order to compile libdispatch

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, clang, llvm, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to compile (parts of) libdispatch, a.k.a. `<dispatch/dispatch.h>` on Windows. I tried with MSVC v140, but since the Microsoft compiler doesn't support Blocks, I guess I'm out of luck with MSVC. My plan is to compile with Clang, which integrates into Visual Studio thanks to those LLVM Snapshot Builds: http://llvm.org/builds/

Trying to compile the blocks example from Wikipedia with that Clang for VS compiler

```
typedef int (^IntBlock)();

IntBlock MakeCounter(int start, int increment) {
    __block int i = start;

    return Block_copy( ^ {
        int ret = i;
        i += increment;
        return ret;
    });
}
```

fails with the error message:

*'__block' undeclared identifier*

What's the problem here? I thought, Clang would support blocks?
What can I do to get this to compile?

Comment: This is more of an Objective-C that a C++ question.

Comment: Ah, right. I've removed the `C++` tag and added `objective-c-blocks`. Still, no need to downvote?!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to specify the compiler flag `-fblocks`?

```
$ clang a.c -fblocks
```

I don't know the default settings of Clang Windows binary, but on OS X (the default is `-fblocks`), with `-fno-blocks` got the same error.

```
$ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix

$ clang a.c -fno-blocks

a.c:3:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__block'
```

Comment: Hmm, according to the doc: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl there is no option to switch on or off blocks. I guess, they just aren't supported by `clang-cl` (yet?).